# Материалы с типом рендера Fade работают не правильно друг с другом

Tags: c#, unity3d, шейдеры, текстура, mesh

У меня есть мир сгенерированный шумом перлина и разделенный на типы высот/биомы.

[image: Мир]
Он состоит из скриптом сделанных мешей (чанков) 60 на 60 клеток каждый.
Но так как я хочу в зависимости от поры года менять цвет каждого биома отдельно (например снег- белый, но гора должна остаться такой же), то я разделил каждый чанк на под-меши, и у каждого своя текстура. Таким образом каждый подмеш отвечает за свой биом.

Иерархия:

[image: Иерархия]

Чанк:

[image: Чанк]

Чанк без одного биома (для наглядности):

[image: Чанк без одного биома (для наглядности)]

У текстур, те пиксели которые находятся на месте где не подходящий биом - прозрачные.
Чтоб это работало мне пришлось менять тип рендера материала каждого чанка на Fade таким вот образом:

```
Material material = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
material.SetFloat("_Mode", 2);
material.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
material.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
material.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
material.EnableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
material.renderQueue = 3000;
```

Но если с тем чтобы эти материалы работали друг с другом нормально я поборолся, то вот есть еще меш воды который тоже должен быть полупрозрачным, как тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот только на этом скриншоте меши чанков не разделены и это одна обычная текстура без прозрачных пикселей на обычном материале с рендер модом Opaque.

А когда я включаю меш воды как Fade то он не работает с мешами чанков которые тоже Fade. И вода отрисовывается то выше чанков, то чанки отрисовываются выше воды. Точнее те чанки что ближе к камере отрисовываются выше воды, а те что дальше - ниже воды:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне правильно сделать?
Или поменять структуру чанков, но как то так чтоб можно было цвет каждого биома менять отдельно, может есть у кого предположения?

Или подружить материалы чанков и воды, только как?

Может есть у кого идеи на этот счет?

PS: Есть вариант сделать материалы мешей как cutout тогда все работает как надо, НО, появляются на краях черные полосы, к тому же эти края совсем не так как хотелось бы работают со светом иногда, может это можно как то исправить?

Черные полосы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выглядит как бордерлендс (может по этому он так и называется потому что там все нарисовано с этими границами? хд).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Генерить для каждого типа свой объект не обязательно. Можно все делать одним используя сабмеши и лист материалов в рендере соответствующие каждому сабмешу по индексу. И при генерации создается какой-нибудь справочник для чанка какие материалы под каким индексом ставидь поскольку не у каждого чанка присудствуют те или иные.

```
_mesh.subMeshCount = 3;
_mesh.SetTriangles(_mountainTriangles, 0);
_mesh.SetTriangles(_forestTriangles, 1);
_mesh.SetTriangles(_grassTriangles, 2);
```

---

На тему материалов `Fade` для таких объектов использовать крайне не рекомендуется и не понятно зачем.

По сути меняя времена года у вас все текстур это непрерывное переходное состояние из одной в другую, например из зеленой летней травы в пожелтевшую осеннюю. Напишите свой простенький `Fragment` шейдер интерполяции текстуры. `Fragment` самый легинький по нагрузке шейдер, [документация в помощь](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexFragmentShaderExamples.html), а `Fade` тяжелый.

```
fixed4 origin = tex2D(_OriginTex, i.uv);
fixed4 target = tex2D(_TargetTex, i.uv);
return origin+(target-origin)*_ProgressValue;
```

Либо в ShaderGraph.

И всего один какой-нибудь объект занимается обновлением `_ProgressValue` и сменой набора текстур при наступлении нового сезона, что тоже просто. `ScroptableObject` с ссылкой на материал и 4 текстуры, а вышеупомянутый объект работает с списком этих `SO` не отличая одного от другого.

Comment: Ответ очень полезен, спасибо)

Comment: Но с ним появляются другие проблемы...
Если меш у меня сделан квадратами по клеткам, то текстуры у меня сделаны не ровно по клеткам.
Каждая клетка логически зарделена 3 на 3 и каждая подклетка состоит из разных закругленных частей по специальной текстурной карте.
А сабмеши работают по треугольникам как я понял, то есть граница изменения цвета будет совсем не по границе изменения текстуры...
Вот если бы можно было сделать сабмеши по пикселям, или прийдется делать частоту треугольников меньше, а значит и чанков больше, потому что есть же граница кол-ва вершин в меше.

Comment: К примеру вот я пытался выделить одну клетку, вот она
http://prntscr.com/aTEHQKo-ozWF

Это сделано для плавности перехода

Comment: Я думал подход более грубый без комбинирования, отпишу чуть позже новым постом, это уже немного другая тема.

Answer (score 3):

**Как комбинировать тайловую текстуры**

Для комбинируемой тайловой текстуры лучший подход это **Marching Squares**.

[image: Marching Squares]

Для квадрата всего 16 вариантов тайлов (можно и с треугольниками). Работает просто, картинка располагается не на тайле, а между ними. Считываем значения наличии текстуры по углам, как двоичные `0` и `1` и суммируем по битам в байт который будет являться номером нужной текстуры. Это самый быстры способ индесирования текстуры и простым образом считаем UV координату каждой вершины, через остаток от деления индекса на длину строки (4) получаем строку и столбик.

```
15 = 8+4+2+1
15 = 1 1 1 1 // двоичное число

5 = 0+4+0+1
5 = 0 1 0 1 // двоичное число
```

---

Данный подход используется к примру в `Warcraft III`.

[image: LordaeronSummerTileSet]

Это `TileSet` травы.

[image: Warcraft3TilesetsEditor]

Таких сетов много, в конкретном уровне используется 6-9 и имеют жесткий порядок прорисовки.

[image: LordaeronSummerSample]

Набор `Lordaeron Summer`. В итоге выглядит симпатично и не квадратно.

---

Обычно генерятся текстуры, но в условиях бесконечно генерящегося мира, да еще и изменяемого в добавок, таким образом можно сожрать всю память на раз.

Придется написать шейдер. Самый легковесный это `Fragment` шейдер работающий по вершинам. Используя `PropertyBlock` [как в этом гайде](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVEP5V01fcE&t=223s), и передавая массив с индексами слоев `int[,]` в каждый экземпляр материала, можно прорисовать ВСЕ в ОДИН `Draw Call`. В итоге память отдыхает, а видеокарта в состоянии с этим справится.

---

[image: MarchingCubesSample]

Такой-же подход используют для смягчения миров сгенерированных из кубов в 3D, называется **Marching Cubes**.

Comment: Систему тайлов я уже и сам разработал, конечно не так как в W3, но теперь с новыми знаниями о шейдерах, мучавшись много времени чтоб разбраться что к чему и как их написать, я смог сделать свой первый собственный шейдер который позволяет устанавливать цвет для каждого типа биома отдельно [Фото](https://prnt.sc/8JXKnvvCZlVt).
Может быть конечно немного костыльно но мне этого с головой)
Огромное спасибо за развернутые и очень поучительные ответы))

Comment: Поздравляю, но если не практиковаться в написании шейдеров, то забудешь как писать на `HLSL` уже через месяц. Я эти азы изучал уже несколько раз заново . А язык еще полезен в написании `ComputeShader`ов для больших вычислений.