# Какой самый эффективный способ передачи данных для отрисовки в шейдер?

Tags: unity3d

Это более не конкретная проблема, а интересующий меня вопрос. Я не особо много работал с шейдерами (почти 0 познаний в них). Сейчас мой код примерно делает следующее:

1. Создаёт "сырые" данные текстуры:

```
NativeArray<Color32> textureData = new(..., Allocator.TempJob);
GenerateTextureJob textureJob = new() {
   ...
};
JobHandle textureHandle = textureJob.Schedule(..., ...);
textureHandle.Complete();
```

2. Создаёт новую текстуру и загружает в неё созданные данные:

```
Texture2D texture = new(chunkSize, chunkSize, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false) {
   filterMode = FilterMode.Point
};
texture.LoadRawTextureData(textureData);
texture.Apply(false);
```

3. Загружает эту текстуру в материал, который потом отобразится через `Graphics.RenderMesh`

Больше половины всего времени в примере выше занимает загрузка и создание текстуры. Какие я вижу решения этого:

1. Передавать через буфер в шейдер сразу "сырые" данные без создания текстуры.
2. Второе решение не сильно отличается от первого, я могу видоизменить джобу и вместо создания `textureData`, просто оставить массив высот по которому я буду определять нужный цвет прямо в шейдере.

Не отрицаю что это может не то что помочь, а лишь сделать хуже.
Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы загружаете текстуру каждый кадр?

Comment: @stanislav-volodarskiy нет, после создания текстуры я её добавляю кэш, если по нужным мне координатам нет текстуры то я создаю её.

Comment: Почему вас волнует время? Текстуру можно создать в параллельном потоке и наложить на материал по готовности. Не очень понятно что за задачу вы решаете.

Comment: @stanislav-volodarskiy это часть генерации мира, меня волнует время потому что за раз может создаваться несколько таких текстур и это создаёт довольно сильную просадку в фпс (со ~180 до 50-60). Про параллелизацию не очень понял о чём вы, можете привести пример или чего-то в этом роде?

Comment: Генерации текстур для чанков нужно избегать, это не только долго, но и память забивает и чем выше разрешение, тем больше. Если текстура заливная из гридиентов, то шейдер должен рисовать её по вершинам. Если текстура блоковая, то [как комбинировать тайловую текстуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1426173/352119). Самый сложный вариант, это масками, как при текстурировании terrain.

Comment: @Yaroslav про память знаю, поэтому сделал что-то наподобие lru кэша, что бы не нужные текстуры и материалы удалялись (изначально хотел сделать пул, но не получилось). В остальном я не очень понял о чём вы, как именно я могу избегать создание текстур (извините, но я не очень в этом разбираюсь). У меня простенькая генерация, которая создаёт текстуру для чанка из набора цветов исходя из шума, [вот как это примерно выглядит](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDmRU-qgOHo)